# Difference between std::fabs(a * b) and std::fabs(a) * std::fabs(b)

Tags: c++, x86, g++, compiler-optimization, clang++

I am working on some numerical code and I was looking at the compiler output. One particular case struck me as odd:

In real numbers, it holds that `abs(a) * abs(b) = abs(a * b)`. I would expect the same to hold in floating point numbers. However, the optimization is performed neither by clang nor by g++ and I wonder whether I am missing some subtle difference there. Both compilers do however realize that `abs(abs(a) * abs(b)) = abs(a) * abs(b)`.

Here is the relevant piece of code:

```
#include<cmath>

double fabsprod1(double a, double b) {
    return std::fabs(a*b);
}
double fabsprod2(double a, double b) {
    return std::fabs(a) * std::fabs(b);
}
double fabsprod3(double a, double b) {
    return std::fabs(std::fabs(a) * std::fabs(b));
}
```

And here is the confusing compiler output in godbolt with gcc-10.1 (current stable version as of writing this) and -O3: https://godbolt.org/z/ZEFPgF

Notably, even with -Ofast, which as far as I understand is more lenient with the transformations that are allowed, this optimization is not performed.

As was pointed out by @Scheff in the comments, double and float are not real numbers. But I also fail to see where corner cases with float types, such as getting Infinity or NaN as argument, could produce different outputs.

Comment: Neither `double` nor `float` are _real numbers_ in the mathematical sense. Hence, it might be that `abs(a) * abs(b) = abs(a * b)` isn't valid in all (edge) cases, and hence is not applied for optimization.

Comment: @Scheff Thanks for the comment, I suspect there is some corner case, hence I asked whether there is a subtle difference for these types. I have thought about what would happen, if one would put Inf, -Inf or NaN for one of the arguments. So far, though, I can't see it. Notably, even with -Ofast , which I think allows some transformations that are invalid for certain corner cases, I don't see that second vandpd getting optimized away. I will edit the question accordingly.

Comment: I just tried to transfer the problem to integrals where this is quite obvious. (E.g. assuming 2-complement, there is no positive value for the min. value of any signed integral type.) Then, I remembered that floating points have a separate sign bit. If there is a reason, it could be a really convoluted one... ;-)

Comment: @Scheff Yes, there is a separate sign bit. One may see in the linked assembly, that ABS operation is implemented by simply resetting this bit with AND (`vandpd`) instruction using a predefined mask. Also, there is no check for any corner cases. The difference between both versions is whether the sign bit is reset on multiplication operands (2x AND) or multiplication result (1x AND).

Comment: Comparable problem with intregrals (int) https://godbolt.org/z/tf3nZN

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe I have found a counter example. I post this as a separate answer, because I don't think that this is at all analogous to the case for integers.

In the cases I considered, I missed that it is possible to change the rounding mode for floating point arithmetic. Problematically, GCC seems to to ignore that when he (I guess) optimizes "known" quantities at compile time. Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cfenv>

double fabsprod1(double a, double b) {
    return std::fabs(a*b);
}
double fabsprod2(double a, double b) {
    return std::fabs(a) * std::fabs(b);
}

int main() {
        std::fesetround(FE_DOWNWARD);
        double a  = 0.1;
        double b = -3;
        std::cout << std::hexfloat;
        std::cout << "fabsprod1(" << a << "," << b << "): " << fabsprod1(a,b) << "\n";
        std::cout << "fabsprod2(" << a << "," << b << "): " << fabsprod2(a,b) << "\n";
#ifdef CIN
        std::cin >> b;
#endif
}
```

Output differs, depending on whether I compile with

```
g++ -DCIN -O1 -march=native main2.cpp && ./a.out
```

or

```
g++ -O1 -march=native main2.cpp && ./a.out
```

Notably, it only takes O1 (what I would consider completely reliable) to change the output in a way that does not seem reasonable to me.

With -DCIN the output is

```
fabsprod1(0x1.999999999999ap-4,-0x1.8p+1): 0x1.3333333333334p-2
fabsprod2(0x1.999999999999ap-4,-0x1.8p+1): 0x1.3333333333333p-2
```

without -DCIN the output is

```
fabsprod1(0x1.999999999999ap-4,-0x1.8p+1): 0x1.3333333333334p-2
fabsprod2(0x1.999999999999ap-4,-0x1.8p+1): 0x1.3333333333334p-2
```

Edit: Peter Cordes (thank you for the comment) pointed out, that this surprising result was due to my failure in telling GCC to respect the change of rounding mode. By building with the following command, the expected results are achieved:

```
g++ -O1 -frounding-math -march=native main2.cpp && ./a.out
```

(works with O2 and O3 as well on my machine).

Comment: Actualy the difference is that without -DCIN, the compiler optimize the computation of the both products by a simple reference to a value computed at compile time. [see assembly here](https://godbolt.org/z/S8L5m5) The value is stored at .LC1. With -DCIN, the product is computed at compile time. That is certainly an optimization miss, but there are no requirement on that.

Comment: Also of intereste, the standard does not requires that compile time computation of floats have the same result of execution time computation: http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#12

Comment: @Oliv thanks for supplying the assembly and the reference to the standard. I figured that the cin would make gcc somehow miss the computation of the values at compile time but I was more concerned about the disregard for the rounding mode in the instance where he did not miss the optimization. 

But with the standard imposing no rules about precision in that matter, I can see how that is legal for GCC to do. And you deduced correctly that I'm concerned with error propagation, but I think it will not be a problem for my application. It is good to know, though.

Comment: IIRC, `-fno-rounding-math` is already the GCC default.  (assume default rounding mode).  Even with that enabled, or even `-ffast-math`, we still don't get this optimization.  https://godbolt.org/z/b7oKLM.  But yes, there *are* circumstances where it's not safe, with some compiler options (and `#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON`), so maybe that's why compilers choose not to look for it.

Comment: Failure to properly tell GCC's optimizer to respect `fesetround` for compile-time constant propagation is why your optimized results are surprising.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you for pointing out that option to me, I was unaware of it. If I add the build parameter -frounding-math I do get the expected result. I edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

Comparable problem with intregrals (`int`) :

```
#include<cmath>

int fabsprod1(int a, int b) {
    return std::abs(a*b);
}
int fabsprod2(int a, int b) {
    return std::abs(a) * std::abs(b);
}
int fabsprod3(int a, int b) {
    return std::abs(std::abs(a) * std::abs(b));
}
```

Results in (using your options `-O3 -std=c++2a -march=cannonlake`):

```
fabsprod1(int, int):
        mov     eax, edi
        imul    eax, esi
        cdq
        xor     eax, edx
        sub     eax, edx
        ret
fabsprod2(int, int):
        mov     eax, edi
        cdq
        xor     eax, edx
        sub     eax, edx
        mov     edx, esi
        sar     edx, 31
        xor     esi, edx
        sub     esi, edx
        imul    eax, esi
        ret
fabsprod3(int, int):
        mov     eax, edi
        cdq
        xor     eax, edx
        sub     eax, edx
        mov     edx, esi
        sar     edx, 31
        xor     esi, edx
        sub     esi, edx
        imul    eax, esi
        ret
```

https://godbolt.org/z/tf3nZN

This contradicts your statement about "real/floating point" numbers.

Overall you shouldn't expect the compiler to shortcut math problems for you. That being said some optimizations is made possible. Please provide documentation or a comparable example where you see the optimaztion.

Comment: 2's complement signed integers have a special case; `-INT_MIN` is signed overflow UB, not a positive integer.  That being the case, compilers could assume that neither `a` nor `b` is INT_MIN, so this is also a missed optimization.  But probably for different reasons: gcc is maybe over-cautious because `abs` itself can overflow.